# getItemAsync returning null or previous value

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm using expo SecureStore and it always returning an old value or the null first time,
In Sign In screen, I am sending a request to get a token and store token

```
                  fetch("https://localhost/api/phlebotomy/login?email=" + email + "&password=" + password, requestOptions)
                    .then((response) => response.json())
                    .then((json) => {
                      if (json.token_type === "bearer") {
                       
                        // console.log(json.access_token);
                        token = json.access_token;
                        save('secure_token', token);
                        
                          navigation.navigate('Home');
                      }else{
                        Alert.alert(json.error);
                      }
                        })
                        .catch((error) => {
                          console.error(error);
                         })
```

And trying to get my token on different screens:

```
const getToken = async () => {
  try {
    const value = await SecureStore.getItemAsync('secure_token')
    if(value !== null) {
      return value;
    }else{
      console.log('Empty Token');
    }
  } catch(e) {
    // error reading value
  }
}
```

I am using this function to store my token

```
async function save(key, value) {
  Alert.alert("Successfully Logged In!");
  await SecureStore.setItemAsync(key, value);
}
```

When I close the app and open it again, it is returning the old value which is stored previously. Could you please help me how can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my issue with replacing fetch with axios. And store token to axios default header

example:

```
    axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] =
      'Bearer ' + response.data.response.access_token;
```

Comment: I have the issue with SecureStore.getItemAsync sometimes returning null. It seems like you "solved" the issue by not using the SecureStore library anymore?